# Instagram Client Error

Tags: python, instagram-api

I am new to the Instagram API. I used the following code from the example on the github to get the most recent popular media.

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
id= "OMITTED"
secret = "OMITTED"
api = InstagramAPI(client_id=id, client_secret=secret)
popular_media = api.media_popular(count=20)                                                                                                                            

for media in popular_media:                                                                     
   print media.images['standard_resolution'].url
```

I get the following error:

```
File "example.py", line 6, in <module>
   popular_media = api.media_popular(count=20)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 197, in _call
 return method.execute()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 189, in execute
content, next = self._do_api_request(url, method, body, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 131, in _do_api_request
raise InstagramClientError('Unable to parse response, not valid JSON.', status_code=response['status'])
instagram.bind.InstagramClientError: (404) Unable to parse response, not valid JSON.
```

I know it is a valid instagram object because when I print(api). I get the following:

```
 <instagram.client.InstagramAPI object at 0x145c2b10>
```

This is taken directly from the example and I can't tell what I am doing wrong! Any help would be great!

Comment: Are you able to print the non-JSON response?

Comment: No because the error is at this line -> popular_media = api.media_popular(count=20)

Comment: If you are following this API documentation and you don't get valid results, that means their code is broken, not yours. That's been my experience, at least. Either that or your keys are bad

Comment: Is it because you're in sandbox mode? [This](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/issues/216) and [this](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/issues/217) seemed to have been caused by attempting to access someone's account other than `self` while sandboxed

Comment: Probably sandboxed. *Apps created on or after Nov 17, 2015* will start in Sandbox Mode **and** All API endpoints require a valid `access_token`

Answer (score 1):

If u signed up after Nov 17th, Instagram popular photo feed is **deprecated** in new API.

The library you are using is old, it will only work for popular API if you had signed up for before November 17th

https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/